# opening/saving xml while preserving newline between node's attributes

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

This is what I have so far:

```
$XML = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$XML.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$XML.Load($path)
#change some node attributes
$XML.Save($path)
```

If I take open an XML file, and take a snippet like this:

```
<Node 
Name="tyjytj" 
Number="rthjr" 
Source="rjyrtjrjrtj" 
BinaryDrive="teheherhehtr" />
```

It will save it like this:

```
<Node Name="tyjytj" Number="rthjr" Source="rjyrtjrjrtj" BinaryDrive="teheherhehtr" />
```

But I want to be able to change (for example) the Name of the Node, while keeping newlines between each attribute. I want the format to remain exactly how it was before I open/saved it.

Comment: I know of no xml parser that allows that. That kind of formatting is not part of the xml structure, so it gets lost when reading xml, changing the in memory structure and then writing it. Also this is not powershell specific. In fact, you are using a .Net class. You might get more answers if you broaden your search to .Net

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. And that's a bummer.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

No XML parser in the world is going to tell you whether the attributes in a start tag are separated by spaces, newlines, or tabs. You aren't supposed to care.

Comment: Readability, changing baselines and modifying makes it a lot easier when new lines are preserved. I think it's worth caring about if it's something you are modifying frequently (as I do in my case).

Comment: @MichaelKay *how* you communicate is just as important as *what* you communicate.

Comment: @user32882 Yes, I should have conveyed the bad news with much greater compassion.

Comment: @MichaelKay, no one's asking you to be Mother Theresa here, but the high number of downvotes suggests that the tone of your answer did a disservice to the truth you wanted to communicate. Furthermore, I personally contest the fact that you "aren't supposed to care". Consider `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxTrivia` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis as an example, which preserves things like whitespace between tokens and comments. If we aren't supposed to care about those things, why does that API go out of its way to store them?

Comment: At least for us, we faced an issue when we wanted to compare 2 XML files using a text comparison tool.

Comment: @JoyGeorgeKunjikkuru The way to do that is to convert both XML files into canonical form.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17968416/1056283) to a question very similar to yours:

While there doesn't seem to be a way of preserving xml attribute formatting, you can define it yourself on the xml document by using the power of the XmlWriterSettings and XmlWriter classes.

You can specify it to have newlines between attributes like so:

```
$xwSettings = new-object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xwSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = $true
```

You then save the document using an XmlWriter together with these settings:

```
$xmlWriter = [Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("c:\temp\newlines.xml", $xwSettings)
$doc.Save($xmlWriter)
```

(Code is all from original answer. Kudos to [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz))

Comment: It requires the Indent property to be set to $true. Hope this will save somebody's time in the future.